# Rails - IMGkit - Errno::EACCES Permission denied error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

I am using IMGkit gem in my rails project.
I also installed `wkhtmltoimage-binary` which is necessary for IMGkit to work.
Both IMGkit and wkhtmltoimage-binary are installed via gemfile.
Under `config/initializers/imgkit.rb` i have

```
IMGKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltoimage = '/Users/Praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/wkhtmltoimage-binary-0.12.2'
  config.default_format = :png
end
```

In `apps_controller.rb`

```
def index

kit = IMGKit.new(html, :quality => 50)

# Get the image BLOB
img = kit.to_img

# Save to a file
file = kit.to_file('/path/to/save/file2.jpg')

# send to browser (Rails - use with #caches_page)
send_data(kit.to_img, :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => 'inline')
```

end

When running this i got the following error

[image]

Though the folder permission is 777. Any help on this to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should show full trace instead of only application trace.

Comment: @Leedy Liu Sry. I didn't get u

Comment: Wasn't the culprit the fact that you tried to save a file to the system?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

No need to give the following in `imgkit.rb` if you install `wkhtmltoimage-binary` via gemfile.

```
config.wkhtmltoimage = '/Users/Praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/wkhtmltoimage-binary-0.12.2'
```